# button gradient or shadow effect 3D in CSS shown at example

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for gradient or shadow effect (I don't know which exactly) like:
[image: button]

thank you for help.

Comment: This cannot be achieved with css, you will likely need to create an image in order to get this effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea using gradient and border to approximate it, simply adjust the color as you need:

```css
.button {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px;
  background:linear-gradient(#ffa797,#e95648);
  box-shadow:0px 1px 2px 2px #ccc;
  position:relative;
  color:#fff;
  z-index:0;
}
.button:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  border-right:15px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  border-left:15px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-top:19px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  border-bottom:19px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="button">some text</div>
```